# Filter query - editing results

Tags: ms-access, select, filter, editing

In MS access, I have a query that i filter with a list of keywords through a second query. The second select query (which acts as a filter) takes the original (data) query and a keyword table and selects from the data query only the entries that match one of the keywords in the list.

I want to edit a field in the resulting query but access doesnt let me. From what i gather from google & Co. My issue might be caused by not having a relationships between the data query and the keyword table. What can i do to enable editing of the data ? If i were to create a relationship between the keyword table and the data query, how would i design it since 1 keyword does not correspond to one entry in the data query.

Edit: here is the SQL code

```
Select Sales.saleID, Sales.saleText1, Sales.saleText2, Sales.clientFirstName, Sales.clientLastName, Sales.clientOk
From Sales, Keywords
Where (((Sales.saleText1) Like Keywords!Keyword)) or (((Sales.saleText2) Like Keywords!Keyword));
```

This returns the correct data but then i cannot edit the clientOk field in the datasheet view (clientOk is a number field)

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Can you please share your code? I don't fully understand your question

Comment: Added the code in the post. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Select 
    Sales.saleID, Sales.saleText1, Sales.saleText2, Sales.clientFirstName, Sales.clientLastName, Sales.clientOk
From 
    Sales
Where 
    (Sales.saleText1 In (Select [Keyword] From Keywords))
    or
    (Sales.saleText2 In (Select [Keyword] From Keywords));
```

Comment: I get an "Invalid Memo, OLE, or hyperlink object in subquery 'Sales.saleText1'." error..is there a problem with the query that constructs Sales ?

Comment: Could be that `Keyword` is a reserved word. See edited answer, please.

Comment: Well, it your tables, and the SQL is pretty simple, so double-check your field names and data types.

Comment: After looking around online, it seems indeed that the fact that saleText1 and saleText2 are long text (memo) types is causing the issue. However i can not change it to short text most of the data is longer than 255 characters. Any ideas how to proceed from there ? Thanks for all the help

Comment: And Keyword? Is that _Long Text_ as well?

Comment: No Keyword is Short Text

Comment: If so, how can `Where Sales.saleText1 Like Keywords!Keyword` return a match when saleText1 typically is longer the 255 characters?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand you question properly, but that line returns a match by looking up if the one of the keywords in the Keywords table can be found in one of the (long text) saleText1. It is not an exact match of course since keyword is never equal to the full saleText1 but it just looks whether keyword is inside the saleText1. It is the code that Access outputs when filtering data with a 'contains..' filter

Comment: But that should be: `WHERE Sales.saleText1 Like "*" & Keywords![Keyword] & "*"`? Or are the keywords stored as, say, `*Joe*`?

Comment: They are indeed :)

Comment: I made a test, and, right, a _Long Text_ won't work with this method. I better delete the answer.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time :) would you have any other workaround then? That wouldn't require the field to be short text?

Comment: Nope. _Long Text_ has many limitations. I would stick with your original query as it runs, write the output to a temp table, use that for your form, and - when finished - update the original table from the temp table.